# Aptana PHP snippets not working

Tags: php, ide, aptana, code-snippets

Aptana PHP snippets aren't working. For example, if I type "if" (if ... else ... snippet ) and hit "tab" or "enter" on the snippet, it does properly expand the snippet to an if ... else ... block. However, if I hit tab to go through the contents of the snippet (like most editors), it just inserts a tab character.

Any way to get these fixed? They weren't broken in the last release, although they weren't very functional.

Comment: I have seen this behavior once before, though I was unable to reproduce. It's reliably reproducible for you?

Comment: NM. reproduced. http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3649. It's currently fixed on the nightly branch, if you'd like to try that.

Comment: Yes. Very reliably in fact ;) Thanks, I'll check out the nightly build!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is fixed in the latest nightly build of Aptana! Thanks guys, wow the new Aptana version sure is fast - seems like the auto complete is faster too, so with that and snippets it makes my PHP coding a lot more efficient.